# IOS Twitter Parse Login with PFLogInViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter, parse-platform, pfloginviewcontroller

All morning I have been trying to login with twitter, as I normally would, but I keep getting the following error:

```
Domain=Parse Code=100 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Parse error 100.)" UserInfo=0x174473540 
{  
   error=Error Domain=com.parse.networking.error 
   Code=-1011 "Expected status code in (200-299),
   got 504" UserInfo=0x174467780   
{  
   NSLocalizedDescription=Expected status code in (200-299),
   got 504,
   NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://api.parse.com/2/user_signup_or_login
},
   temporary=1,
   code=100
}
```

I am logging this out in the:

```
- (void)logInViewController:(PFLogInViewController *)logInController
didFailToLogInWithError:(NSError *)error;
```

Some Additional notes:

Before today I had never had any trouble with my twitter login. I was having problems with some cloud code that was causing the login to fail for Facebook. Even when I rolled the code back it turned out to not be the case. After some testing I believe the issues are completely unrelated.

I am extending the PFLogInViewController provided by parse and implementing my login screen. Facebook and regular login works fine. To add to this, twitter login has worked a few times (three times, non consecutive).

I looked around but I have no clue why this is only happening when I try to login with twitter.

Comment: I'm also getting the exact same error with the same setup - I have a very simple PFLogInViewController just to include a logo and over the last few days I noticed that Twitter logons would either take a long time or time out.  Recent attempts have yielded the same error that you noted above and I haven't changed anything on the Parse side or the Twitter side.

Comment: I'm also getting the same error. Any resolution?

Comment: Nothing yet. Still looking for an answer. No leads so far.

Comment: I can  confirm that this issue is currently also affecting the REST API as well as the android sdk

Comment: I see, so you're saying this is a parse problem?

Comment: @SuperKevin not sure, it could also be twitter related, I have seen something like this once before and it resolved itself within a day, and still have never been able to figure out the root cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i had the exact same problem but it went back to normal for me like an hour ago.

Answer (score 0):

It was a big issue Parse side, for more informations about this issue, this is thread about this issue :

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/914545211986956/